# How do I get and set the path for input type=file?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I need to create a `greasemonkey userscript` which can get the path of an uploaded image, store it, and then set it on a different page's `upload input`.

As far as I understand it is not possible to figure out the file path on an `input type=file` with `javascript` alone.

But is this possible with `greasemonkey`?

How close can I get to the desired functionality and what options do I have?

So far I have tried to access the `input's` value via `val()` but it doesn't work at all.

**EDIT:**

If I can't get the path, can I at least set it, provided I always use the same folder?

Comment: you can use TamperMonkey on Chrome, which is better than Greasemonkey anyway, and then you can use file.files[0].webkitRelativePath. still not everything you want, but might be better than nothing. in terms for steering a file open box a certain folder; you can't.

Comment: sounds interesting! can i save the "value" of a file input using this? eg c:/... etc? Perhaps copy it in clipboard that may work?

Comment: webkit exposes a number of properties and the file contents. you can save them if you want using localStorage or a download, or a server, or something more imaginative...

Comment: researching this issue further returns this thread in google :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get this value, but you can upload a specific local file using [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).
You will need to ask users to change the config `greasemonkey.fileIsGreaseable` to `true`.

Have you tested to use Greasemonkey just to change the action of the form to the new page?
I haven't tested it, but I think you should give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've not used GreaseMonkey before, but based purely on this line

> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of **JavaScript**.

I'd suggest it's not possible. To understand why, you have to understand the reasoning behind the security measures. Imagine JavaScript **was** able to read/write to the `input[type='file']`, malicious JavaScript could automatically create a form, create the file input, set it's value to something like `c:\\\Windows\\System32\\Some Sensitive File`, and then post the form, all without your consent.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, but is not secure. You cannot change the value of an `input type="file"` using JavaScript.